# Java Exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting ----prefix" when starting Jenkins Service

Tags: java, jenkins

I'm upgrading a Jenkins server to [2.357](https://updates.jenkins.io/download/war/2.357/jenkins.war) and I've upgraded Java to 11 from 1.8 to support it.

However, when I start the Jenkins, it fails and `journalctl -xe` gives the below error

```
   Server.
    -- Subject: Unit jenkins.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    -- 
    -- Unit jenkins.service has failed.
    -- 
    -- The result is failed.
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 systemd[1]: jenkins.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
    -- Subject: Unit jenkins.service has finished shutting down
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    -- 
    -- Unit jenkins.service has finished shutting down.
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 systemd[1]: Starting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server...
    -- Subject: Unit jenkins.service has begun start-up
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    -- 
    -- Unit jenkins.service has begun starting up.
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 jenkins[19752]: Running from: /usr/share/java/jenkins.war
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 jenkins[19752]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting ----prefix=VALUE but found no value
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 jenkins[19752]: at winstone.cmdline.CmdLineParser.parse(CmdLineParser.java:60)
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 jenkins[19752]: at winstone.Launcher.getArgsFromCommandLine(Launcher.java:415)
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 jenkins[19752]: at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:385)
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 jenkins[19752]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 jenkins[19752]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 jenkins[19752]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 jenkins[19752]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 jenkins[19752]: at Main._main(Main.java:332)
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 jenkins[19752]: at Main.main(Main.java:114)
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
    -- Subject: Unit jenkins.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    -- 
    -- Unit jenkins.service has failed.
    -- 
    -- The result is failed.
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
    Jul 11 14:28:57 jenkins01 systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
    Jul 11 14:28:58 jenkins01 systemd[1]: jenkins.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
    Jul 11 14:28:58 jenkins01 systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
    -- Subject: Unit jenkins.service has finished shutting down
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    -- 
    -- Unit jenkins.service has finished shutting down.
    Jul 11 14:28:58 jenkins01 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for jenkins.service
    Jul 11 14:28:58 jenkins01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
    -- Subject: Unit jenkins.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    -- 
    -- Unit jenkins.service has failed.
    -- 
    -- The result is failed.
    Jul 11 14:28:58 jenkins01 systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
    Jul 11 14:28:58 jenkins01 systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
```

Looks like it points to the exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting ----prefix=VALUE but found no value` but I can't seem to figure it out. A help would be appreciated!

Java Version:

```
openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.15+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.15+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Are you passing `--prefix` as a startup parameter?

Comment: No, I'm simply using `sudo service jenkins start` to start the service

Comment: Check your service definition and verify it's not passed there. Probably located at `/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service`

Comment: Thanks! I changed it from `Environment="JENKINS_OPTS=-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true --prefix"` to `Environment="JENKINS_OPTS= --prefix="` as I no longer use emails. It worked!

Comment: @ycr If you can put your suggestion as an answer, I can mark it as correct. Thanks for the help too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that you are somehow passing the `--prefix` startup parameter with an invalid value. `--prefix` is only needed if you have a custom context path for Jenkins.

If you are starting your Jenkins server as a service, check the service definition and make sure only the required parameters are passed. The service definition is located at `/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service`